# Connection partially Encrypted - Part not transmitted over SSL

Tags: apache, ssl, https

I'm wondering how I can find out where the culprit is, as to what is NOT being transmitted over SSL on my website.  It's blowing my mind, because I use relative URLs or explicitly choose HTTPS:// for all links, images, etc...

Any ideas/tools to find out what the issue is?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "Connection partially Encrypted"? There is no STARTTLS in HTTPS

Comment: Check out Piskvor's response.  FireFox tells me my connection is only PARTIALLY secure - and of course I'd like to get it to be fully!

Comment: Well, technically it's not really a single connection, but I suppose FF uses that text as to not confuse the users.

Comment: OK so if you're looking for a mixture of secure and non-secure requests relating to the same page, then add the vhost and referer to your access logs (you do use a differently named vhost for the SSL stuff don't you?)

Comment: @symcbean: Good point, would you like to add it as an answer? Note however that with modern pages, not all the requests go to hosts under your control (various click analytics, CDNs, mashups and other doodads, etc.).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean that some resources are transferred over HTTP without encryption, you can check for this in Chrome's Developer tools in the tab Resources - that should tell you which parts come from where - look for those with address starting with `http://` .

Alternately, use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com/fiddler2/version.asp): by default, it won't decrypt HTTPS connections, so you'll be seeing CONNECT requests for HTTPS, and GET/POST for HTTP - those are your culprits.

Comment: Chrome was a GREAT tool.  Thanks a million, found it!

Answer (score 1):

For those, like myself, who run into this issue i suggest a few tips while designing your website.

Always use relative paths when ever possible "images/someimage.png" instead of using domain paths like `http://someDomainName/images/someimage.png` so on. Any one of these and it will cause the browser to throw that warning at you.

When linking to external content, Google/other Ads, javascript sources(such as jquery, so on), or any other media... make sure you use a https:// link if they have one available. Myself, i had one tiny image for a link to an external site but they did not offer a https link to the image, so i simply downloaded it and put it in my images folder. Problem solved.

The Chrome resources list is a very helpful tool, not sure if Firefox has something similar in its tool box. Another method, if you have shell/command line access, is to use grep to search the files for "http:". This, most often, will show anything that is linking to non secure content.